# Microsoft office gets slow for Large file editing

Tags: performance, microsoft-office

I have around 4500 pages in a file which is a mixture of text, and images. I am using a slightly modified template of the normal template ( Just heading style, page size, margin changed).

Now whenever I try to edit the file, the complete files become extremely slow and sluggish.

I have tried with "SHOW PICTURE PLACEHOLDERS". However, it is still too much slow.

***Could you please tell me how can I handle such a large docx file without getting sluggish?***

P.S. My computer AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6 core processor and I have 16 GB RAM, Radeon RX 5500 XT.

Comment: Are you using Office 32-bit or 64-bit. If 32-bit, consider switching to Office 64-bit.

Comment: 4500 pages is really a lot, especially for a word document. It will require a lot of memory to keep everything loaded which means it is likely swapping constantly to disk which makes it rather slow. If you have 32-bit version of Office, then it can only utilize 3,5GB of memory max rather than as much memory as it needs, though 4500 pages may even consume more than 16GB of memory, so it may still swap. Also, if the file itself is on a network share, constant saving/loading in the background will harm performance too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an ungodly length for any word processing software to handle. I would personally try to split it up into different files. For example, chapter 1 would be Chapter1.docx, chapter 2 would be Chapter2.docx, and so on.

Comment: My ultimate target is to combine them as an interactive pdf with bookmarks, index. In that how can I create and update the index? How to update the bookmarks?

I wonder how a big pdf is created if they are not a single file.

Comment: @Marufuddin At this point, it might be beneficial to look beyond your typical Word Publishing software and look at Tex or variants of, depending on how much formatting you need doing.